# Scene is unreachable ... does not have an identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I am getting this warning:

> Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an
>   identifier for runtime access via - instaniateViewControllerWithIdentifier

While Xcode is correct about no entry points, it does have the following defined:

```
Custom Class : Class = ViewControllerCatalog
Identify : Storyboard ID = vccatalog
```

What else do I need to define to avoid this error?

Comment: an entry point?  just try adding a hidden button with a segue from some other view controller and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to transition to a scene in a storyboard: You can either segue to it or you can instantiate it using its storyboard identifier. But the warning is pointing out that you have neither any segues nor storyboard identifier, and therefore have no way to ever instantiate that scene. You can instantiate the base class, but unless you use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, the storyboard scene (and all of its controls and all of the `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` references) cannot be used. And in order to use that storyboard method, the scene obviously needs a storyboard identifier.

So, if you're not going to use segues, that must mean you're going to transition to this scene programmatically. So, first make sure to specify the storyboard identifier:

[image]

And then instantiate your `DetailsViewController` linked to that scene like so:

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsScene")   // or, if you need to access custom properties, `storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsScene") as! DetailsViewController`

// now use it as you see fit, e.g.,
//
// showViewController(controller, sender: self)
```

Comment: But i do have a storyboard ID - that is what I do no understand. Exactly as your screenshot shows. I will try upload a screenshot later

Comment: Argh - ### I had an empty view placed elsewhere - answer acceped :)